# Why i am getting maximum trigger depth exceeded. System.DmlException Upsert failed?

Tags: class, triggers, salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

Please help! I am getting an error when After update trigger is running. the error is -
System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AddProductsToCartafterupdate: maximum trigger depth exceeded.

When I separately run this class - CreateCartOnQuoteUpdate.addMultipleProducts(i) by passing the paramter, it works fine.

```
trigger AddProductsToCartafterupdate on Test_Config2__CartSystem__c (After Update) 
{
ID i;
string AXflag;
integer count;
for(Test_Config2__CartSystem__c  pc:Trigger.new) 
{
     i = pc.Id;
     AXflag = pc.AX_Flag__c;
     count = Integer.valueof(pc.Count_of_tempitems__c);
}
    If(AXflag == 'addprods' && count >= 1)
    {
     CreateCartOnQuoteUpdate.addMultipleProducts(i);
        
    List<Test_Config2__CartSystem__c> Pcupdate = [Select ID, AX_Flag__c, Test_QPConfig__Proposald__c from Test_Config2__CartSystem__c where ID = :i];
    For(Test_Config2__CartSystem__c p: Pcupdate)
  {
     p.AX_Flag__c = null;
        update p;
   }
        
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is happening because of a recursive call you are trying to update records from the same object again and again before the records committed to the database.

you should use trigger.before not after and there is no need for DML operation then.

```java
trigger AddProductsToCartAfterUpdate on Test_Config2__CartSystem__c (before update) {
    Id i;
    String AXflag;
    Integer count;

    for (Test_Config2__CartSystem__c  pc: Trigger.new) {
        i = pc.Id;
        AXflag = pc.AX_Flag__c;
        count = Integer.valueof(pc.Count_of_tempitems__c);
    }

    if (AXflag == 'addprods' && count >= 1) {
        CreateCartOnQuoteUpdate.addMultipleProducts(i);
        
        for (Test_Config2__CartSystem__c p: Trigger.new) {
            p.AX_Flag__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

answer from @Moustafa is only half way correct.

You still have a lot of issues in your code:

- Assign `i` and `AXflag` inside a loop and use it outside => you will only process the last element of the list (`Trigger.new`)
- Don't respect naming convention
- Loop twice over `Trigger.new` => impact performance
- Update in a loop is something very wrong as you will hit governor limits => [read tuto](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk)
- I wonder what are you doing in `createCartOnQuoteUpdate.addMultipleProducts`

```
trigger AddProductsToCartAfterUpdate on Test_Config2__CartSystem__c (before update) {
    for (Test_Config2__CartSystem__c  pc: Trigger.new) {
        if (
            pc.AX_Flag__c == 'addprods'
            && Integer.valueof(pc.Count_of_tempitems__c) >= 1
        ) {
            createCartOnQuoteUpdate.addMultipleProducts(pc.Id);
            
            pc.AX_Flag__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```